# Implement (or use) a lock screen

Tags: android

Is there a way I can use the android default lock screen (SDK)? OR should I implement my own? If I implement my own Any pointers how to do that?

I basically want to unlock the screen using the keypad and If I use certain pattern then I can receive calls from X only and if I use a different pattern then I can receive calls from Y only (X and Y being certian contact).

Please help me .. I need hint and I can take it from there
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint: from JNI invoke the Android's lock screen. Still with NDK you can find how to unlock it programatically if a call received. I mean on a none rooted phone too!!!  OFC this will not be a 2 line of code which will write here.